# duplicate buttons

Tags: qt, layout, copy

I have the following problem I've been struggeling with. I have a list of toolbuttons placed in a scroll area. I want to make a second scroll area with push buttons that duplicate the text of the tool buttons, but only for the toolbuttons that are selected. For example let's select toolbuttons 1,2 and 3. Then when I push an "update" button, a scrollarea with pushbuttons 1,2 and three should appear. This is my code:

CPP-file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

scrollArea.setParent(ui->centralWidget);
scrollArea.setGeometry(50,50,200,300);
scrollArea.setWidget(&viewport);
viewport.setLayout(&layout);

scrollArea2.setParent(ui->centralWidget);
scrollArea2.setGeometry(350,50,200,300);
scrollArea2.setWidget(&viewport2);
viewport2.setLayout(&layout2);

update.setParent(ui->centralWidget);
update.setGeometry(50,400,100,50);
update.setText("update");

addButtons();

connect(&update,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(refreshScrollArea()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::addButtons()
{
for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
{
    QToolButton *button = new QToolButton;
    button->setCheckable(true);
    buttons<<button;
    buttons[i]->setText(QString::number(i+1));
    buttons[i]->setMinimumSize(200,50);
    layout.addWidget(buttons[i]);
}

viewport.resize(200,5*50);
}

void MainWindow::refreshScrollArea()
{
while (!layout2.isEmpty())
{
    delete layout2.takeAt(0);
}

int selected_index=0;

for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
{
    if (buttons[i]->isChecked())
    {
        QPushButton * button = new QPushButton;
        button->setText(buttons[i]->text());
        layout2.addWidget(button);
        selected_index++;
    }
}

viewport2.resize(150,50*selected_index);
}
```

header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private slots:

void addButtons();
void refreshScrollArea();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;

QVector<QToolButton*> buttons;

QScrollArea scrollArea;
QScrollArea scrollArea2;

QVBoxLayout layout;
QVBoxLayout layout2;

QWidget viewport;
QWidget viewport2;

QPushButton update;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Main:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

When I push the update-button once, it works perfectly, but when I select different tool buttons and push update again it seems like the buttons are being stacked as if the layout is not empty. However when I select no toolbutton and push update there are no buttons, so the layout is emptied. Can anybody see what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

An example of the 'update' code:

```
// you clear your duplicate layout
int num = layout2->count();
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i
{
    delete layout2->itemAt(0);
}

// you create duplicate buttons for checked initial buttons
for (int i = 0; layout1->count(); ++i)
{
   QPushButton* btn = (QPushButton*)layout1->itemAt(i);
   if (btn->isChecked())
   {
        QPushButton* newBtn = new QPushButton;
        newBtn->setText(btn->text());
        layout2->addWidget(newBtn);
    }
}
```

If you don't need to create and delete new buttons again and again, you can have constant set of buttons and just show and hide them.